# Insert byte into a byte array

Tags: java, arrays, byte

I really can't believe I'm asking this but everything I read is either converting from int to byte to string to byte or something. I am literally trying to insert a byte into a byte array. Or for that matter, initialize a byte array with bytes, not ints.

```
byte[] header = {0x8b, 0x1f, 0x00, 0x08, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x03};
```

The compiler complains that they are ints. I'm trying to insert bytes.

Answer (score 9):

`byte` is a signed integer in the range `[-128,127]`. `0x8b` is `139d`, so you'll need to cast it to a byte `(byte)0x8b` or use a value in the proper range such as `-0x75` (the equivalent of casting `0x8b` to `byte`).

Comment: Thank you. I had a feeling it was something very simple. I feel kind of bad for even having to ask.

Comment: don't feel bad, it's not obvious at all. other languages (like C) will accept similar code without even warning sometimes...

Answer (score 3):

The compiler threats literals like `0x8b` as integers, so you have to explicitly cast to byte

```
byte[] header = { (byte) 0x0b, (byte) 0x1f };
```

Answer (score 3):

Bytes are signed integers, so cannot exceed 127. `0x8b` is therefore too big.

[Reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
public static byte[] bytes(byte... bytes){ return bytes; }

byte[] header=bytes(0x8b, 0x1f, 0x00, 0x08, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x03);
```